# innodb buffer pool reserves the memory in advance?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, innodb

I have 64 GB linux m/c out which DBA have allocated innodb_buffer_pool_size = 40G which mean 24 GB is available for rest of the processes + OS. My question is : Does allocated innodb_buffer_pool_size reserve the memory in advance and wont give that memory back to OS or other processes whenever there is additional need ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you don't change the size, it will be allocated at the startup and will not be "given back" as long as mysqld runs.

And you must have enough memory free for the defined size, or else mysql will not start

> InnoDB allocates memory for the entire buffer pool at server startup, using malloc()
> operations. The innodb_buffer_pool_size system variable defines the buffer pool size.

see [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/memory-use.html)

Comment: so that much memory will be reserved in advance by mysql

Comment: yes, when you start mysqld it will allocate the memory

Comment: heavy duty Database servers usually run on its own

Comment: My impression is that the cache grows over time.  But never shrinks.

Comment: there are more than one cache, but the buffer_pool_size doesn't change.